# git vs. subversion

Tags: git, svn, version-control, dvcs

I'm looking for ammunition to convince a customer to switch from subversion to git for handling the *large* source code it has to manage. 
I'm personally convinced of the benefits with git after researching the topic quite thoroughly for a a few weeks, I have also used it in a few smaller private projects where it really shone.
My customer will likely be more persuaded by objective monetary benefits than my personal anecdotes. Are there any studies of version control studies programs that can show the benefits of alternatives to svn in an objective way?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, how exactly *will* a switch to git make your customer more money?

Comment: If the repository is on SVN already, let it stay there. Implement new, original features in their own repo, this could be git. Let the transition happen in time, there's no need to rush things up. And doing this transition will cost money - the devs will have to retrain for the new SCM.

Comment: It will cost money, time and education to change - those are probably reason enough not to do it.  SVN handles large projects fine - we have one with over two million files and 20,000 revisions in it.

Comment: The only ammunition this is is for a flame war. For what it's worth, git handles large code repositories well. It does *not* handle large binaries well. At all. (I'm a git fan myself and that's a major limitation.)

Comment: "My customer will likely be more persuaded by objective monetary benefits" - uh, objective monetary benefits are kind of what business runs on! If - and it's a big "if" - SVN is a better for for the business and has a monetary advantage, why on earth would you try and sell them on something else?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A healthy branch per feature regiment is possible. It would be much harder with svn. The benefits are here:

https://plus.google.com/109096274754593704906/posts/R4qkeyRadLR
(make sure to read the comments)

Speed is very significant. The fact that you are working locally for most of your work, you gain a lot of productivity.

3-way merge vs. baseless merging. In SVN there is no way to know what the base is when you are in a merge conflict. This makes branching and merging a huge pain. Not so with GIT.

There are many others too. But this should be a good start.

Hope this helps.